# Latex \index doesn't work with \textbf

Tags: latex

I'm using this package `\usepackage{imakeidx}` in my latex project.
I would like to have bold indexed text but I have problems.
When I write `\index{\textbf{some text}}` the text does't appear.
If I write `\textbf{some text}` or `\index{some text}` everything work correctly.
I know how to make index bold `\index{Sam@\textbf{Sam}}` but I don't know how to make text bold.
What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I must write the 2 separate commands, I can not combine them into one.